# How to use GCC from MSYS instead of the GCC that i have on PowerShell 7

Tags: gcc, mingw-w64, msys2

I've installed gcc with MSYS2 using `pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain` and got the following output when i do `gcc --version` on MSYS2 MINGW64

```
gcc.exe (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

But got the following output when doing it on powershell

```
gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I want to use the GCC on MSYS2 inside of my powershell, how would i do that?

Comment: Use `which` or local equivalent to get a full path to each copy of gcc, and set your PATH to make sure the one you want comes first. (On POSIX shells the equivalent to `which` is `command -v`; offhand I have no idea what it is in powershell but `which` itself may be aliased, so try it first and Google if it doesn't work).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy On powershell its ```get-command```, i have the PATH but don't know how the positioning works, which one comes first? the one at the top or at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Add the location of the desired `gcc.exe` at the beginning of your `PATH` variable.

In PowerShell this looks something like this:

```
$env:Path = 'C:\mingw64\bin;' + $env:Path
gcc --version
```